# Detecting Bash Pipes

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that optionally reads bash pipes for input, this works fine for most cases. Yet when you drop it into yet another pipe on fd0, my script reads the parent pipes data because - for whatever reason - in Bash  (on Linux) they are the same pipe.

```
#!/bin/bash 
numstr=${1}
rdlnk=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/0)

function get_input() { 
 ## echo "PID: $$, PPID: $PPID " && sleep 500 
 ## What works is:  
 ## if grep -Eq "^pipe:|deleted" <<< "${rdlnk}" && [[ "${rdlnk}" != "$(readlink /proc/$PPID/fd/0)" ]]; then 
 if grep -Eq "^pipe:|deleted" <<< "${rdlnk}"; then 
  while IFS= read -r piped_input || break; do numstr="${numstr}${piped_input}"; done  
 elif [[ -f "${rdlnk}" ]]; then 
  numstr=$(head -1 "${rdlnk}")  
 elif [[ -e "${numstr}" ]]; then 
  numstr=$(head -1 "${numstr}")
 fi 
}

get_input 
echo "the number string ${numstr} ..." 
exit 0
```

I have fixed this problem as you can see in the comment in the code itself, by looking at the parent process fd0. What I would like to know is if there is a better/more proper way to do this?

Note: If you want to take a closer look at this, you may want to uncomment the first line and take a look at `ls -al /proc/[PID|PPID]/fd/0`.

To test this out, save the script above to a file `/tmp/test.bsh`.

```
$> for a in {1..5}; do /tmp/test.bsh "$a"; done
the number string 1 ...
the number string 2 ...
the number string 3 ...
the number string 4 ...
the number string 5 ...

$> while read a; do /tmp/test.bsh "$a"; done < <(seq 1 5)
the number string 12345 ...
```

If you swap commented conditionals you will see that both now work properly.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your scripts stdin (fd0) should be pulling data from the parent's stdout (fd1). Why are you trying to access the parent's stdin?

Answer (score 2):

When you get this deep into the specifics of one shell and one OS, you should ask if that's really the water you want to be in.

I can't reproduce your behavior.  On my system:

```
$ while read a; do ./test.sh "$a"; done < <(seq 1 5)
the number string 1 ...
the number string 2 ...
the number string 3 ...
the number string 4 ...
the number string 5 ...
```

Or, more conventionally,

```
$ seq 1 5 | while read a; do ./test.sh "$a"; done   
the number string 1 ...
the number string 2 ...
the number string 3 ...
the number string 4 ...
the number string 5 ...
```

But that's probably because that system isn't Linux ....

The real issue is that, if I may, you're caring about the wrong thing.  You're working backwards from a file descriptor instead of letting the user define it in whatever way is most convenient.

If you want to read from standard input, do that.  If you don't, have the user name the input as a command-line argument.  That's how *everything* works.  When you start investing yourself in how fd0 was defined and how your script was invoked, you're defeating the OS's purpose of defining standard input and standard output in the first place.  And, however you do that, you're bound to introduce weird cases.

If you need to know whether standard input has a specific feature -- because that affects what you can do with it -- that's what **stat**(1) is for.  Or just try to use it the way you want, and branch on a predictable error e.g. `ESPIPE`.